# How to change a negative value at the birthday that has already been this year

Tags: php

Be so kind and help me please, I have problem with negative displaying the number of days, which has already been and the rest will be next year. Example: when is today 2016-03-29 and birthday od some person are every year 27. March, with PHP done by me is written "dayToBirthday" value  "-2", but the right is "363". I am not able to write condition "if dayToBirthday< 0, else dayToBirtday +365 days". Please can you help me, thank you very much.

```
<?php
.
.
. //connection
.
.
$action = '';
$sql = "SELECT members.*, datediff(CURDATE(),DATE_FORMAT(birthday, concat(YEAR(CURDATE()), '-%m-%d')))*(-1) AS dayToBirthday, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,birthday,CURRENT_DATE) as age FROM members";
$where = '';
if(isset($_GET["id"])) {
    $id = $_GET["id"]; //geting id value which we are passing from table headers
    $action = $_GET["action"]; // geting action value which we are passing from table headers
    //we are checking condition if $action value is ASC then $action will set to DESC otherwise it will remain ASC

    if($action == 'ASC') {
        $action='DESC';
    } else {
        $action='ASC';
    }
    if($_GET['id']=='id') {
        $id = "id";
    } else if ($_GET['id']=='name') {
        $id = "name";
    } else if($_GET['id']=='birthday') {
        $id="vorname";
    }

    $where = " ORDER BY $id $action ";
    $sql = "SELECT members.*, datediff(CURDATE(),DATE_FORMAT(birthday,     concat(YEAR(CURDATE()), '-%m-%d')))*(-1) AS dayToBirthday,     TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,birthday,CURDATE()) as age FROM members" . $where;
    }
?>
```

Comment: MySQL table is classic: "name" and "lastname" (VARCHAR), "birthday" (DATE)

Comment: Can you please explain: ` I am not able to write condition` Why not? are you not using SQL? do an `IF ELSE` condition and alter the value as needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this query with a `IF` condition comparing current month/day with birthday month/day:

```
    SELECT members.*,
           IF
           (
             SUBSTR( CURRENT_DATE, 6, 5 ) > SUBSTR( birthday, 6, 5 ),
             TIMESTAMPDIFF( DAY, CURRENT_DATE, STR_TO_DATE( REPLACE( birthday, YEAR(birthday), YEAR(NOW())+1 ), '%Y-%m-%d' ) ),
             TIMESTAMPDIFF( DAY, CURRENT_DATE, STR_TO_DATE( REPLACE( birthday, YEAR(birthday), YEAR(NOW()) ), '%Y-%m-%d' ) )
           ) as dayToBirthday,
           TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,birthday,CURRENT_DATE) as age
      FROM members
```

Note that I use an *extravagant* substring comparison instead of more confortable `DAYOFYEAR` to avoid problems on leap years.

<kbd>**[sqlFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3a631/2)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can use If statement in query, try this

```
select if(CURDATE() > @birthday this year@, datediff(date_add(@birthday this year@, interval 1 year), curdate()), datediff(@birthday this year@, curdate())) as diff;
```

in @birthday this year@ just past correct value

Comment: Can you help me? I´m new in PHP. 
How exactly do I have to write a query. Which row. Completely, please. Column (date of Birth) have name "birthday".
Thanks